# Creating a scroll window with dynamically created buttons in a certain part of the screen:

Tags: python, user-interface, button, kivy

I have this code which creates dynamically, based on the items inside a list, kivy buttons. I now have this idea to create these buttons inside a "box" of sorts which is scrollable. I currently have the layout you can see in the picture, in which the red box should be scrollable area, so that the rest of the layout can stay fixed to their position.

I was thinking about about a vertical box Layout at first, but I cant find to figure out how to tell my buttons to "bind" to the scrollable box.

This code creates my buttons (rn it creates them stacked on top of each other. This is what I use self.h for.):

````
items = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
def create(self, list=items):                                               #Creates Categorie Buttons
        self.h = 1
        for i in list:
            self.h = self.h - 0.2
            _btn = Button(text= f"{i}", size_hint=(.2,.22), pos_hint={"center_y":self.h, "center_x":.5}) 
            add_fun = partial(self.writeFile, your_arugment=i)
            _btn.bind(on_press=add_fun)
            self.list_of_btns.append(_btn)   
            self.add_widget(_btn)
```

And here is the .kv file I have be experiment with, I do not think this is of any use but anyway:

```
       ScrollView:
            size: self.parent.size
            pos: self.parent.pos
            background_color: 1,1,1,1
            GridLayout:
                rows:6
                cols: 1

                background_color: 1,1,1,1
                size_hint: 1,None
                height: self.minimum_height
                Label:
                    text: 'Example 1'
                    background_color: 1,1,1,1
                Label:
                    text: 'Example 1'
                    background_color: 1,1,1,1
                Label:
                    text: 'Example 1'
                    background_color: 1,1,1,1
                Label:
                    text: 'Example 1123'
                    background_color: 1,1,1,1
                Label:
                    text: 'Example 1'
                    background_color: 1,1,1,1
                Label:
                    text: 'Example 1'
                    background_color: 1,1,1,1
                Label:
                    text: 'Example 1'
                    background_color: 1,1,1,1
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out myself but for those who might need the answer themselves:

Its pretty much just creating a normal screen in .kv language, and then defining where to put the scrollview.

````
self.contend_scroll_view = GridLayout(size_hint_y=None, row_default_height=150, cols=1)
        self.contend_scroll_view.bind(minimum_height=self.contend_scroll_view.setter('height'))

        #Creating dynamically buttons based on items in list. 
        for i in MAIN.items:
            btn=Button(text=f"{i}",size_hint=(.2,.22), font_size= 60, font_name= "Arial Bold")
            add_fun = partial(self.writeFile, your_arugment=i)
            btn.bind(on_press=add_fun)
            self.contend_scroll_view.add_widget(btn)

        # Putting the scrollView on the screen with the right position. 
        self.scroll_view = ScrollView(pos_hint={"center_y": 0.45, "center_x":0.5}, size_hint=(.70,.55))
        self.scroll_view.add_widget(self.contend_scroll_view)

        # Add the two Widgets to Home Screen
        self.add_widget(self.scroll_view)
```
````